# Processing URLs which contain symbols on another language

Tags: r, encoding, web-scraping

I working on a web-scraping tool project which collects data from Reddit via "RedditExtractoR" R-package.
The package allows getting URLs of posts by the search query. Then I getting content from posts by each URL.

The problem is that some URL has symbols from another language, which R cannot process correctly.

For example the bellow URL returns the error:
"http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij\363n/"

```
In file(con, "r") : cannot open URL 'https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij������n/.json?limit=500': HTTP status was '503 Service Unavailable'
```

The original URL is: [https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gijón/](https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij%C3%B3n/)

As I understood there is some encoding problem. The R can't processed this string of URL because there is contain "ó" symbol which recodes by R as "\363n".

So, how to change encoding for correctly processing this kind of URL in R?

Comment: did you try to use the function URLencode() ?

Comment: Interesting!

Here the result which I get from URLencode():
http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij%F3n/

Unfortunately, URL doen't work. Maybe you can advice some specific parameters for my case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mind to use a package for that but, `urltools` seem to be a good place to start.

```
library(urltools)
some_url <- "https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gijón/"
# it could be also a vector of url's
puny_decode(some_url)
```

gives the result:

```
[1] "https://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij\xf3n/"
```

It gives me the right page, if I copy it to a browser.

Sorry for the misleading comment about the `URLencode()` but it seemed promising, however it can't deal with utf characters.

Comment: Since in the comments the links are somehow looking strange, I can't understand what don't work as it should. It would be easier to help you if you could provide an reproducible minimal example in your question.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, the RedditExtractoR package provides the following link for processing: http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij\363n/

So, your code should look like this:

`library (urltools)
some_url <- "http://www.reddit.com/r/Barca/comments/4g4fmp/match_thread_fc_barcelona_vs_sporting_de_gij\363n/"
puny_decode (some_url)`

The result is an incoming link with no changes.

My problem is decoding the "\363n" part of the link to "ó" or something which R can process as a URL.